# A question about the use of Silverman's Specialization Theorem

Tags: elliptic-curves, function-fields

In the book "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves", 2nd Edition, by Silverman, there is a theorem called Silverman's Specialization Theorem (Theorem 20.3 pp. 457) which states that:

Let $K$ be a number field, let $C/K$ be a curve and let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over the function field $K(C)$. Assume that $E$ is nonconstant, i.e., $j(E)\not\in K$. Then the specialization map
$$\sigma_{t}: E(K(C))\longrightarrow E_t$$
is well-defined and injective for all but finitely many points $t\in C(K)$.

My question is, is there a way to conclude the injectivity of the specialization map without satisfying the assumption that the $j$- invariant is not in $K$?

I am working with elliptic curves $y^2 = x^3 + a(t)$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ whose $j$-invariant is $0$ and I want to use the injectivity of the specialization map.

Comment: Have you looked at the second volume of Silverman, *Advanced topics…* ? The theorem is stated as Theorem 11.4, p. 271. The assumption seems weaker (that the elliptic surface is non-split), and I think you can backtrack to where the assumption is needed (at least the fact that sets of bounded canonical height are finite, p. 218 – this assumption is discussed in the following section).

Comment: @Aphelli, Can you confirm that the condition that the elliptic surface is non-split, is somewhat equivalent to the condition that the $j$-invariant is nonconstant or the quantities $c_6$, $c_4$ and $c_6/c_4$ are not, sixth power, fourth power and square in $\mathbb{Q}(t)$?

Comment: You should definitely check out the discussion in Silverman, I don’t know this topic so well. But, as I understand it, “nonsplit” means that the elliptic curve $E/K(C)$ is not isomorphic over $K(C)$ to a curve $E_0 \otimes_K K(C)$, where $E_0/K$ is an elliptic curve. In your case, that’s probably (although not certainly, again, I don’t know these subtleties very well) equivalent to $a(t) \notin K(C)^{\times 6}\cdot K$.

Comment: @Aphelli, thanks I appreciate it